# Excel VBA: Compile Error 13 while using numbers in col. M to add rows and copy down data from col. N and O

Tags: excel, vba

I am running this block of code that looks for product quantities in column M and if the quantity is greater than 1 it inserts a row beneath that value and copies data down from column N to fill the cells that were added.

I need it to also look for data in column L and do the same thing as it does in column N.  Currently if there is text in column N I am getting a Runtime 13 error in Excel.

```
Sub InsertRowsAndFillDescriptions()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim arrData, rngData As Range, arrRes
    arrData = ActiveSheet.Range("M1").CurrentRegion.Value
    ReDim arrRes(1 To Application.Sum(Range("m:m")), 1 To UBound(arrData, 2))
    k = 1
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        For j = 1 To arrData(i, 1)
            If j = 1 Then arrRes(k, 1) = arrData(i, 1)
            arrRes(k, 2) = arrData(i, 2)
            k = k + 1
        Next j
    Next i
    Range("M2").Resize(k - 1, 2).Value = arrRes
End Sub
```

This code was not written by me so I don't know how to modify it to accomplish this.
I have added an image of the starting state and end state of this macro once complete.

[image: Excel Starting State and End State]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `CurrentRegion` inlcude more columns. `arrData(i, 1)` is not from Col M anymore.
- Change: loading Col L, M, N into an array.

```
Sub InsertRowsAndFillDescriptions()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim arrData, rngData As Range, arrRes, lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
    arrData = Range("L1:N" & lastRow).Value
    ReDim arrRes(1 To Application.Sum(Range("M:M")), 1 To UBound(arrData, 2))
    k = 1
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        For j = 1 To arrData(i, 2)
            If j = 1 Then arrRes(k, 2) = arrData(i, 2)
            arrRes(k, 1) = arrData(i, 1)
            arrRes(k, 3) = arrData(i, 3)
            k = k + 1
        Next j
    Next i
    Range("L2").Resize(k - 1, 3).Value = arrRes
End Sub
```

Comment: It WORKS!!! Thank you so much.  I still have a mountain in front of me on this project but this document is now complete!